# sol/python .env issues freecodecamp

Tags: python, solidity

newbie here! I am following along with the freecodecamp tutorial and up until this point I have had no issues with the .env files. However, as I am working on the full-stack section at the end of the video it seems as though my .env file is throwing errors.

I have downloaded the verbatim syntax from the github repo and still it is prompting errors so the problems seem to originate on my end.

export PRIVATE_KEY = 0x104XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID = 89ccXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

The problems that pop up are saying that a declaration or statement is expected, cannot find name 'PRIVATE_KEY"/"WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID". I have since installed yarn as a new package; could this be contributing to the issues?

Thank you so much for your help and if I need to post any more info I am more than willing to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problems I am posting the 'solution' to this issue rather than removing the thread. Restarting my computer seemed to fix the issue. Who would have thought that would be the answer....